# string.format automatically pads my double how do I make it stop

Tags: java, double, string-formatting, padding

example input:

```
double a = 31.3131313131313131313131313131313131131313131313131313131313131;
String value1 = String.format("N= %1$39.32f", a);
System.out.println(value1);
```

example output:
    N= 31.3131313131310000000000000...

Why would my program automatically pad when there are values called for? How can I control this as I would like the values to be called.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with double precison, take a look at this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a = 31.3131313131313131313131313131313131131313131313131313131313131;
    System.out.println(Double.toString(a));
}
```

output:

```
31.31313131313131
```

The java `double` datatype cannot hold this much precision. Use a `BigDecimal` instead.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("31.3131313131313131313131313131313131131313131313131313131313131");
    System.out.println(a.toPlainString());
}
```

output:

```
31.3131313131313131313131313131313131131313131313131313131313131
```

Answer (score 0):

Because a `double` can only represent 53 bits of precision, which is roughly 16 decimal digits of precision.  So your variable `a` is simply being initialised with the nearest representable value to the one that you requested.

If you really need this level of precision, you should consider using [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).